# Are there any more modern screen saver options for GNOME?

Tags: screensaver, xscreensaver, gnome-screensaver

I would like a more modern screensaver than xscreensaver or a way to configure xscreensaver to *look* better.

Comment: You mean like gnome screen saver ? https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeScreensaver

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I don't think so. I'm installing it right now to see if it's what I want.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I just unzipped the file and read the `Readme` and it says to refer to the `INSTALLATION` file on how to install it. However, there is no `Installation` file.

Comment: If you are running gnome it should be installed already. If not `sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver` . Why are you downloading or installilng outside of apt-get / software center ? https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome+screensaver&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I am running GNOME but I guess it wasn't installed because, when I ran `apt-get install gnome-screensaver` it installed it as well as `gnome-power-manager`. What I have right now simply turns the screen black. [This](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZestyZapus/Alpha2/UbuntuGNOME) is what I'm using right now.

Comment: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeScreensaver/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Last question: how do I run it/replace my current screen saver?

Comment: I would remove xscreensaver if you don't use it. Should work out of the box.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen xscreensaver isn't installed. Should it have been originally?

Comment: No I misunderstood . gnome screen saver shuld be active by default

Comment: @bodhi.zazen You mean that, once installed, it's active by default, overriding the one that came with Ubuntu GNOME?

Comment: Do you mean one of `apt-cache search screensaver`?

Comment: Is there anything modern about the notion of a screen saver these days? :-)